# How to center vertices of a gltf model

Tags: gltf

I have a gltf model, where vertices are not centered around 0,0,0.

My app retains the origin defined in the model but the model vertices are not centered around the (0, 0, 0) point which leads to it being not drawn at the location I would like it to be drawn.

But, when I use gltf viewer online, or microsoft model viewer in windows 10, those tools center the model at 0,0,0

I would like to know if there is a tool or a way in code in order to center a gltf model.

Comment: What framework?  ThreeJS?  BabylonJS?  Cesium?  Other?

Comment: I am working Cesium